# Undefined index when posting to php

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, ajax

```
thisBtn = $(this); 
parent = $(this).parent(); 

num = parent.data('num'); 
var id = parent.attr('id'); 

if(typeof num != 'number'){ 
    num = 0;
}

$(this).attr('disabled', true); 
$.post('javas.php', {num: (num+1), id: id}, function(data) { console.log('Ajax success');  
parent.next('.status').html(data); 
thisBtn.attr('disabled', false); // reset  });

console.log('Ajax success'); 
parent.data('num', ++num); 
parent.next('.status').html(data); 
thisBtn.attr('disabled', false); // reset
```

I am trying to send the variable id to a php page (javas.php). However I am receiving an undefined index error but I am not sure why, I am retrieving the I on javas.php with the $_POST method and num is being sent correctly with no error, any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: "Undefined index" sounds like a PHP error. Could you post the PHP code as well, and the exact error message?

Comment: Where does the error occur? php or javascript.

Comment: when i try echo the id in php

Comment: Post the PHP code, please. There's no way to help without seeing it.

Answer (score 2):

validate that

```
var id = parent.attr('id');
```

returns something other then undefined, as if it is undefined it wont get sent.

Answer (score 0):

Use Firebug to check what data is being sent over. Without being able to see the code, it's hard to be sure, but it looks like a scope issue - `parent` is global whereas `id` is local.

Answer (score -1):

The error is because you are trying to access an element of an array that doesn't exist... Presumably the $_POST array.

The reason for the element not existing is likely either a typo in your php code (double check that you have typed the key correctly), or your post parameters in the JavaScript are incorrect (again, likely a typo).